# page title name is not coming in page source using angular js site

Tags: angularjs

Page title name is not coming in page source but page title is showing at right place..but when I open page source page title is not come as I expected.

page title is showing in page source like this mentioned below here

```
<title ng-bind="ngMeta.title"></title>
```

but the real title is not showing at page source..but real title is showing when I mouse over the place where page title shows.how to solve the problem..I am using angular js.can anyone help me please ?

Comment: what do you expect?

Comment: i am excepting the title name like 
<title>some title</title>

Comment: instead of <title ng-bind="ngMeta.title"></title>

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Comment: It's a client side javascript. content will replace with actual result only in browser. you will not see the actually result in *view-source*

Comment: But it is a problem for seo..

Comment: It's same as Javascript changing content after page load. So you will unable to see the content in view source.

Comment: so what i have to do????please help me